# Multiple DKIM and SPF DNS records

Tags: google-app-engine, spf, dkim, mailgun

We uses both Mailgun and Google App engine mail services to send transaction emails from our products. Both needs `DKIM` and `SPF` text record in the DNS server. Is it possible to set multiple `DKIM` and `SPF` record in `DNS` configuration? Will it work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You would only need a single SPF record as you can have multiple rules within it. Check [this article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4568483?hl=en&ref_topic=2759192) for assistance on setting up more than just Google's entries in your SPF record.. Your DKIM signature will specify the subdomain on your domain to check for the signature key. Google Apps uses the `google._domainkey` subdomain when it specifies the DKIM location to lookup. I'm not sure what mailgun uses but chances are it won't overlap.

**Update**:

After a quick look around I found [this article](http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#verifying-your-domain) on Mailgun's website and would think your SPF record should look like this:

`v=spf1 include:mailgun.org include:_spf.google.com ~all`

Comment: In mailgun, it says to set domain key for hostname `mx._domainkey`.

Comment: In my case, Mailgun requires a TXT record for `k1._domainkey` which clashes with the CNAME record for `k1._domainkey` as required by MailChimp.